# Loading multiple dependent javascript web resources in a Dynamics Form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

We have a JavaScript Web Resource with a function that is being triggered on the Contact Form's onload event. Configured in Form Properties.

The callback function is triggered, but we are seeing very random results with the libraries that the callback depends on.

These JavaScript libraries are setup as JavaScript Web Resources in Dynamics 2015.  These are added to the Form Properties and are listed in the order they depend on each other, the the callback code last in the list.

Dynamics seems to load these just fine, but executes each one as soon as it is loaded, rather than in the order specified in Form Properties. This often leads o the callback code (which is very small) firing before the larger libraries have initialized.

Does anyone know why this happens, or of a way to guarantee libraries are loaded and initialized in the order stated in Form Properties?

Comment: Good question; I am experiencing the same behaviour in Dynamics CRM 2011 RU 17. On what version is your code running?

Answer (score 0):

Anytime I've seen this type of behavior, it has been due to code being run when the script is loaded instead of having CRM call the load function to start initialization. Will you make sure that nothing in these scripts are using the jQuery's `$(document).ready()` or anything similar?

CRM highly depends on itself calling the load functions that are defined before any code that is dependent on Xrm.Page api running.

Comment: `Xrm.Page` is now deprecated as of v9.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/get-started/whats-new/customer-engagement/important-changes-coming#some-client-apis-are-deprecated